# Pygame drawable text class fails to draw

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a class that represents a bit of text that can be drawn to the screen. This class is intended to be used in relation to a `Window` object that, when it is drawn, passes a subsurface of the surface it was given to the `draw()` function of the text element.

The window draws, but the text does not. Nor does it draw when I invoke the TextElement's draw() function directly. I've examined the code with a debugger, and the blit is definitely being done. I've also tried switching the font to `"Arial"` instead of letting Pygame grab the default.

```
import pygame

#Background and edge color of windows
global bgcolor
global bordercolor
global txtcolor
#Pygame font object that most text will be drawn in
global mainfont

#Defaults; code that imports us can change these.
#Black background with white borders & text
bgcolor=(0,0,0)
txtcolor=(255,255,255)
bordercolor=(255,255,255)
#This will give us whatever font Pygame is set up to use as default
if not __name__== "__main__":
    #Font module needs to be initialized for this to work; it should be if we're imported, but won't if
    #we're being executed directly.
    mainfont=pygame.font.SysFont(None,12)
else:
    mainfont=None


class Window:
    """The base UI class. Is more-or-less a way to draw an empty square onto the screen. Other things are derived from this.
    Also usable in its own right as a way to manage groups of more complex elements by defining them as children of
    a basic window."""

    def __init__(self, rect):

        self.rect=rect

        #'children' of a window are drawn whenever it is drawn, unless their positions are outside the area of the window.
        self.children=[]

    def draw(self, surface):
        "Draw this window to the given surface."

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, bgcolor, self.rect)
        #Draw non-filled rect with line width 4 as the border
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, bordercolor, self.rect, 4)

        self._draw_children(surface)

    def _draw_children(self,surface):
        "Call draw() on each of the children of this window. Intended to be called as part of an element's draw() function."
        for thechild in self.children:
            #We use a subsurface because we only want our child elements to be able to access the area inside this window.
            thechild.draw(surface.subsurface(self.rect))

class TextElement(str):
    """A bit of static text that can be drawn to the screen. Intended to be used inside a Window, but can be drawn 
    straight to a surface. Immutable; use DynamicTextElement for text that can change and move."""

    def __new__(cls,text,font,rect=pygame.Rect((0,0),(0,0))):
        self=super().__new__(cls,text)
        self.image=font.render(text,True,txtcolor)
        self.rect=rect
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return str.join("",("TextElement('",self,"')"))

    def draw(self,surface):
        self.image.blit(surface,self.rect.topleft)

class DynamicTextElement():
    """A bit of text whose text can be changed and that can be moved. Slower than TextElement."""

    def __init__(self,text,font,rect):
        self.text, self.font, self.rect = text, font, rect

    def __repr__(self):
        return str.join("",("DynamicTextElement('",self.text,"')"))

    def draw(self,surface):
        image=self.font.render(self.text,True,txtcolor)
        image.blit(surface,self.rect.topleft)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    mainfont=pygame.font.SysFont(None,12)
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    mywindow=Window(pygame.Rect(150,150,600,300))
    mytext=TextElement("Hello world! This is static, immutable text!",mainfont,pygame.Rect((200,200),(100,100)))
    mydyntext=DynamicTextElement("And this is dnyamic, movable text!",mainfont,pygame.Rect((200,230),(100,100)))
    print(mytext.image)
    mywindow.children.append(mytext)

    clock=pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill((55,55,55))
        mywindow.draw(screen)
        mytext.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW: in `blit()` you can use `self.rect` in place of `self.rect.topleft`

Comment: have you try to run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see errors ? I got error in `__new__` in `TextElement()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
    self.image.blit(surface, self.rect.topleft)
```

but should be

```
    surface.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
```

`surface` and `self.image` in wrong places.

You tried to draw surface on text.

You have the same problem in `DynamicTextElement()`

---

**BTW:** I use Python 2 so I had to use `str`

```
self = str.__new__(cls,text)
```

in place of `super()`

```
self = super().__new__(cls,text)
```